# How to create a pseudo-tty for reading output and writing to input

Tags: unix, stdout, stdin, tty

I am using fork() and execvp() to spawn a process that must believe it is connected to an interactive terminal for it to function properly.

Once spawned, I want to capture all the output from the process, as well as be able to send input to the process.

I suspect psuedo-ttys may help here. Does anyone have a snippet on how to do this?

Comment: This is indeed exactly what pseudo-ttys are for. I often wish that Windows had a similar capability built-in.

Answer (score 7):

You want to call forkpty().  From the man page:

> #include <pty.h>  /* for openpty and forkpty */
>
> pid_t forkpty(int *amaster, char *name, struct termios  *termp,  struct
>     winsize *winp);
>
> Link with -lutil.
>
> The forkpty() function combines openpty(), fork(), and  login_tty()  to
>     create a new process operating in a pseudo-terminal.  The file descrip‐
>     tor of the master side of the pseudo-terminal is returned  in  amaster,
>     and the filename of the slave in name if it is not NULL.  The termp and
>     winp parameters, if not NULL, will determine  the  terminal  attributes
>     and window size of the slave side of the pseudo-terminal.

Your parent process talks to the child by reading and writing from the file descriptor that forkpty stores in "amaster" - this is called the master pseudo-terminal device.  The child just talks to stdin and stdout, which are connected to the slave pseudo-terminal device.

Comment: forkpty() is on Linux and Mac, but not e.g. Solaris or AIX.  If you want portability, POSIX defines the functions posix_openpt(), ptsname(), grantpt(), and unlockpt().

Comment: Aye it is a BSD standard, inherited by Linux.

Answer (score 1):

There's a package called "expect" which you should use.  It uses a scripting language called tcl (pronounced tickle).

https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/

Comment: Although the expect web site looks amateurish, expect has been around for many years so it's a solid package.

Comment: Since the OP begins with "I am using fork() and execvp() to spawn a process..." it is clear that they want to include this functionality in an existing program, not rewrite it in TCL for expect.

Answer (score 0):

[Expect](http://sourceforge.net/projects/expect/) was already mentioned for use via Tcl, but it can also be used without Tcl by treating it as a C library and calling the API [documented here](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.5/expect/libexpect.3.html)