# How to respond to a prompt of a program launched with `system`?

Tags: c

I know how to pass an argument to `system`, for example:

```
char words[]="abcde";
sprintf(str, "echo %s",words);
system(str);
```

I write a simple code to brute-foce crack a rar file.

But I don't know how to pass password to `system` when the prompt appears.

I try this code below

```
char pw[512];
for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
    char ch=i+'a';

    memset(pw, '\0', sizeof(512));
    system("unrar x filename");// prorgam will wait at this point for a password
    sprintf(pw, "%c",ch);   
    system(pw); //this line doesn't make sense....
}
```

How can I pass that data to `system` when the program is waiting for input?

Comment: No you cannot send data from your program directly to the subprocess started with system(), see my answer.    system() does not return until the program finishes.   popen() lets you communicate with the subprocess by returning a FILE * connected to the stdin/stdout of the subprocess

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply and teaching.Sorry that I don't choose your reply for best answer.Both of your answers are very good!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unrar lets you supply the password as part of the command-line:

```
for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ++ch) {
    char cmdline[512];
    sprintf(cmdline, "unrar -p%c x filename", ch);
    system(cmdline);
}
```

Comment: Tnanks for your reply.But can I pass data to system when system is waiting for?I just want to know how to do it.

Comment: Not with `system()`. `popen()` lets you either write to a child process's stdin or read from its stdout, but not both. If you want both, that's much more difficult and hazardous. You need to give the child process a pseudo-tty to trick it into thinking that its talking to a keyboard and screen. Otherwise, it may misbehave quite badly because of I/O buffering. This is especially important for passwords, which are usually entered via something other than stdin (which echoes to the screen).

Comment: Hmm...that sounds difficult. I think me have some ideas about how to do it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2579069: That worries me. This problem is known to be difficult and tricky to get right even when you know what you're doing. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203652/how-to-create-a-pseudo-tty-for-reading-output-and-writing-to-input) for guidance on the best way forward (i.e., someone else has done the hard work for you).

Comment: Keep in mind that providing a password via command line is generally a bad idea, since a process's command line is usually available to all other users in a system without much difficulty. I know that this is only for a single archive... but still.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `system()` if you want to directly interact with the command you specify, since it states in the `system()` description that `system()` does not return until the specified command finishes: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_system.htm.

As Marcelo noted, if the program you want to send data to accepts command line parametes, just specify the data on the command line you pass to `system()`.   Another approach if the program you want to call takes data on the stdin is to save the data to a temporary file, then specify a stdin redirect on the command line, then after `system()` returns delete your file:

```
char *inputFileName = mkstemp("/tmp/myinputXXXXXX");
// store data in inputFileName
char buf[128];
sprintf(buf, "/path/to/myprogram < %s", inputFileName);
system(buf);
unlink(inputFileName);
```

If you need to interact with the program you run, you need to use another set of library functions to start the process and set up an IPC mechanism between them.   The std library has a function similar to `system()` which lets you do this: `popen()`.   `popen()` lets you specify a command line similar to `system()`, but it creates a pipe to the created program and returns a FILE * which lets your calling program read, write, or both, data from/to the subprocess:

```
FILE *myprogFP = popen("/path/to/myprog", "rw");
fprintf(myprogFP, "%d\n", i);
pclose(myprogFP);
```

For more information and examples of handling error returns from these functions, see for example: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-to-a-Subprocess.html

Comment: this solution is much more generally useful